# Docker Compose does not bind ports

Tags: docker, fig, docker-compose

I have the following Dockerfile for my container:

```
FROM        centos:centos7

# Install software
RUN         yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN         yum install -y tar gzip wget && yum clean all

# Install io.js
RUN         mkdir /root/iojs
RUN         wget https://iojs.org/dist/v1.1.0/iojs-v1.1.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN         tar -zxvf iojs-v1.1.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /root/iojs
RUN         rm -f iojs-v1.1.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

# add io.js to path
RUN         echo "PATH=$PATH:/root/iojs/iojs-v1.1.0-linux-x64/bin" >> /root/.bashrc

# go to /src
WORKDIR     /src

CMD         /bin/bash
```

I build this container and start the image with `docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 -v /srv/source:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app --rm iojs-dev bash`. Docker binds the port 8080 to the host port 8080, so that I can access the iojs-application from my client. Everything works fine.

Now I want to start my container with docker-compose, using the following docker-compose.yml

```
webfrontend:
    image: iojs-dev
    links:
        - db
    command: bash -c "iojs test.js"
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
    volumes:
        - /srv/source:/usr/src/app
        - /logs:/logs
db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
```

When I now run `docker-compose run webfrontend bash` I can not access the port 8080 on my host. No port was binded. The result of `docker ports` is empty and also the result of `docker inspect` is empty at the port settings:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "docker0",
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.51",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:33",
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "8080/tcp": null
    }
},
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "/srv/source:/usr/src/app:rw",
        "/logs:/logs:rw"
    ],
    "CapAdd": null,
    "CapDrop": null,
    "ContainerIDFile": "",
    "Devices": null,
    "Dns": null,
    "DnsSearch": null,
    "ExtraHosts": null,
    "Links": [
        "/docker_db_1:/docker_webfrontend_run_34/db",
        "/docker_db_1:/docker_webfrontend_run_34/db_1",
        "/docker_db_1:/docker_webfrontend_run_34/docker_db_1"
    ],
    "LxcConf": null,
    "NetworkMode": "bridge",
    "PortBindings": null,
    "Privileged": false,
    "PublishAllPorts": false,
    "RestartPolicy": {
        "MaximumRetryCount": 0,
        "Name": ""
    },
    "SecurityOpt": null,
    "VolumesFrom": []
},
```

Comment: The [latest RC release of 1.1.0-rc2](https://github.com/docker/fig/releases) (it's now called docker-compose) supports the `--service-ports` flag, which will bind the ports during `fig run`.

Comment: @dnephin Thanks, I was about to give up on my custom `run` script. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional behavior for `fig run`.

> Run a one-off command on a service.
>
> One-off commands are started in new containers with the same config as a normal container for that service, so volumes, links, etc will all be created as expected. The only thing different to a normal container is the command will be overridden with the one specified and **no ports will be created in case they collide**.

[source](http://www.fig.sh/cli.html).

`fig up` is probably the command you're looking for, it will (re)create all containers based on your fig.yml and start them.

Comment: You are right and I should better RTFM ;-)
It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

This is intentional behavior for `docker-compose run`, as per [documentation](http://docs.docker.com/compose/cli/#run):

> When using `run`, there are two differences from bringing up a container normally:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. **by default no ports will be created in case they collide with already opened ports.**

One way to overcome this is to use `up` instead of `run`, which:

> Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Another way, if you're using version 1.1.0 or newer, is to pass the `--service-ports` option:

> Run command with the service's ports enabled and mapped to the host.

P.S. Tried editing the original answer, got rejected, twice. Stay classy, SO.